# I need to have an increasing number everytime i load in (i use Jsf). My current code is only random numbers,and im slow

Tags: java, html, css

My numbers random,i need it to start from 1 and end at 1000, increasing by 1 each time.

i tried a bunch of things,the code for my full project is here.

[text](https://jsfiddle.net/ELTON_JOHN/wsgn5tfc/30/)

`m`

Comment: Just to confirm if I understand correctly. The number that currently in your code works as random do you want it to count from 1 to 1000, using it as a trigger every time the page is refreshed?

Comment: yeah (sorry for late response)